# Owner of incrond file products?

Tags: linux, cron

Please [1] consider this command: `sudo incrontab ~/incron-config` where `~/incron-config` contains:

```
/home/zetah/doc IN_CREATE,IN_MOVED_TO /home/zetah/scripts/do_something.sh $@/$#
```

and `do_something.sh` consists of [2]:

```
#! /bin/bash
python /home/zetah/scripts/py_something.py "$1"
```

Python script accesses some online services and produces 3 new files. They are owned by `root`.
Why is that and how can I change this behavior. I want to be the owner of those product files

Thanks

---

*[1] Posted on Ask Ubuntu previous - thought to try my chances here, will interlink in any result

[2] Seems lame to wrap Python script in Bash script, but I couldn't do it otherwise*

Comment: Question is answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/60054/who-is-owner-of-incrond-file-products/60067#60067 The thing was, I shouldn't have run incrontab with `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

created files are owned by root probably because you run incrontab as root and then python inherit from it through bash

You can run incrontab from your own user, simply add your username in /etc/incron.allow (to allow you to use incron) and then recreate the incron table with your account with "incrontab -e" (don't forget to remove the entry from root)

Second option (if you can't modify incron.allow) is to call python with your username.
In your bash script, modify :

```
python /home/zetah/scripts/py_something.py "$1"
```

in

```
su <username> -c"python /home/zetah/scripts/py_something.py '$1'"
```

Hope it's help

ericc